# NoMethodError in PaymentsController#summary, undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am getting the following error:

> NoMethodError in PaymentsController#summary
>
> undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
> Extracted source (around line #134):

```
132    format.pdf do
133    pdf = SummaryPdf.new(@klasses)
134    send_data pdf.render, filename: "Payments Summary_#{AcademicTerm.current.details}.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
135   end
136 end
137end
```

SummaryPdf is a class responsible for printing the income summary of the payments in a school. It is defined under the payments controller as

```
def summary
  @klasses = Klass.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {render "summary"}
    format.pdf do
      pdf = SummaryPdf.new(@klasses)
      send_data pdf.render, filename: "Payments Summary_#{AcademicTerm.current.details}.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :payments do
  get 'search_form', :on=>:collection
  get 'klass_menu',:on =>:collection
  get 'byklass',:on =>:collection
  get 'enrolment',:on =>:collection
  get 'bystudent',:on =>:collection
  get 'with_balance', :on=>:collection
  get 'fully_paid', :on=>:collection
  get 'all_with_balance', :on=>:collection
  get 'all_fully_paid', :on=>:collection
  get 'summary', :on=>:collection
```

So, anyone who can help me with the solution?

Comment: for nil:NilClass is the key part of this error.  It's saying that you don't have an object at all.  This likely means one of the initialized values here in this controller isn't working.  Install the ```pry``` gem and insert ```binding.pry``` into your controller code so you can begin inspecting the state of the variables here with a live IRB session from your server terminal as your code executes.  That should let you identify what object is nil.  My suspicion is that it's either send_date or the ```pdf``` variable.

Comment: thanx, let me try that option

Comment: But what i know is that i dont have a pdf object,,, any idea of how i can add it to my code?

Comment: If you don't have a pdf-object then you should save it firsthand (the answer I posted). Use `SummaryPdf.create(@klasses)` or `pdf.save` between lines 133 and 134.

Comment: when i use SummaryPdf.create(@klasses), I get an error saying undefined method create, and when i use pdf.save, I get an error saying undefined method save

Comment: What is the tool you are using to generate a pdf-view? I googled quite a bit and discovered it looks quite [prawn-ish](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn)- am I right?

Comment: Sure, thing is am trying to change my app from ruby to jruby, and in the ruby code, i was using prawn, but when i apply it here i get a nomethoderror saying uninitialized method prawn and yet i have it as part of my gems

Comment: You might want to try `require "prawn"` at the top of your code.  You need to post more info about the specific error and how you tried to implement it for us to know.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what that `render` method does exactly on line 134 but are you sure you can call it on an unsaved `SummaryPdf` object? I'd say `render` method needs a saved instance of it.

Comment: Render method helps you to keep on the same page your on when you refresh that page

Comment: I'd also say that my SummaryPdf object is saved, unless otherwise #notsure but what do you mean by render method needs a saved instance of it?